Is there a way to add a background image to each list item in a list?
I'm building another website and the background is a watercolor type painting and I wanted to make it where every nav button had an image of a watercolor splatter behind it. I've been trying to figure it out but nothing has worked.
Here is my current attempt but nothing I've tried has worked yet:


nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2% 6%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: right;
}

.nav-links {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

.nav-links ul {}

.nav-links ul li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-links ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(https://assets.onecompiler.app/42tzva7s5/42wnuqh5j/water%20drop.png);
  background-position: relative;
}
<nav>
  <div class="nav-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">LORUM</a></li>
      <li><a href="">LORUM</a></li>
      <li><a href="">LORUM</a></li>
      <li><a href="">LORUM</a></li>
      <li><a href="">LORUM</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>




CSS property position has the value relative but background-position doesn't have a value relative.

Give this CSS a shot:


nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2% 6%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-links {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

.nav-links ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-links ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-links ul li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  /* Required for the pseudo-element */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Make sure the link text is on top */
}


/* Add a pseudo-element for the watercolor background */

.nav-links ul li::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url('https://assets.onecompiler.app/42tzva7s5/42wnuqh5j/water%20drop.png');
  background-size: contain;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 0;
  /* Make sure this is behind the link text */
}
<nav>
  <div class="nav-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">LORUM</a></li>
      <li><a href="">LORUM</a></li>
      <li><a href="">LORUM</a></li>
      <li><a href="">LORUM</a></li>
      <li><a href="">LORUM</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>



Using a pseudo-element (::before in this case) is a good way to add custom elements to each item in a list, or every child div

This property should work in any element. Looks like the only thing missing is the url enclosed in quotes.
background-image: url("https://assets.onecompiler.app/42tzva7s5/42wnuqh5j/water%20drop.png");


I hope the following code snippet is your desired result. You might want to change the background-size property to either cover or contain, depending on your preference. The snippet here uses contain.


nav{
  display: flex;
  padding: 2% 6%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: right;
}

.nav-links{
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}
.nav-links ul li a{
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  background-image: url(https://assets.onecompiler.app/42tzva7s5/42wnuqh5j/water%20drop.png);
  background-size: contain; /* u could change this to cover too */
  background-position: center; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">LORUM</a></li>
      <li><a href="">LORUM</a></li>
      <li><a href="">LORUM</a></li>
      <li><a href="">LORUM</a></li>
      <li><a href="">LORUM</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>




That does work, but when i use cover it cuts off the top and bottom of the image. How do i fix that?

@SexyLexi what do you mean ? the li element is rectangular, and your image is a square, they will never have the same size!

Well true but is there a way to make my li element height bigger so that I can fit the whole image?

Hey there! Sorry for the late response,
Try changing the padding values. I suggest trying out:
padding: 20px 12px; (You may have to adjust these depending on the text) and
padding: 12px 12px;.
As Mister Jojo pointed out, The element is rectangular while the image is a square. You could try tinkering with width and height properties on the li element if you still dont get your desired result. Have a nice day!

Your question really lacks precision on what you are looking to achieve.
Here is what I understand from it...
PS: the <menu> tag seems more appropriate here.


menu {
  list-style  : none;
  display     : flex;
  align-items : center;
  gap         : 1em;
  }
menu li {
  display           : flex;
  align-items       : center;
  background-image  : url(https://assets.onecompiler.app/42tzva7s5/42wnuqh5j/water%20drop.png);
  background-size   : contain; 
  background-repeat : no-repeat;
  aspect-ratio      : 1 / 1;
  }
menu li a {
  color            : black;
  text-decoration  : none;
  cursor           : pointer;
  font-weight      : bold;
  }
<menu>
  <li><a href="">LORUM</a></li>
  <li><a href="">LORUM</a></li>
  <li><a href="">LORUM III large</a></li>
  <li><a href="">LORUM 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Rum</a></li>
</menu>




Your background-image is very large (775x731px) and is displayed at original size (because there is no background-size definition in your css), which has the effect that only its top-left is "displayed" behind the li elements. But that top-left of the image is a transparent area, so you don't see anything.
Add these three settings to achieve proper size and position of the background-image:
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;

"contain" shrinks it so that it completely fits into the element's boundaries, "no-repeat" avoids multiple display of the image (which would happen in this case), and "background-position: center;" centers it horizontally and vertically inside the element.
BTW: background-position: relative; is invalid.


nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2% 6%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: right;
}

.nav-links {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

.nav-links ul {}

.nav-links ul li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-links ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  background-image: url(https://assets.onecompiler.app/42tzva7s5/42wnuqh5j/water%20drop.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
<nav>
  <div class="nav-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">LORUM</a></li>
      <li><a href="">LORUM</a></li>
      <li><a href="">LORUM</a></li>
      <li><a href="">LORUM</a></li>
      <li><a href="">LORUM</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>




Right way would be to use list-style-image of li element.


#image {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  list-style-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4621/treehouse-marker.png);
}
<div>
  <h3><code>list-style-image</code></h3>
  <ul id="image">
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>



